# Im making a virtual Assitant on python and i dont know why speech recognition doesnt listening and prints the what i have said

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, google-assistant

So as I said I'm making a Virtual Assistant using Python and speech recognition doesn't listen to me it doesn't print what I have said. Below is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_audio():
    print("listening...")
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))
        
    return said


get_audio()
```

And after I run and debug the code as python it only says me listening to I talk as loud as I can on the microphone but don't work. My task bar shows that python is using a microphone but still don't work and I'm using vscode.

Please everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, based on your description, your code keeps on listening and I think that's the problem. Now I'll give an updated code below

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_audio():
    print("listening...")
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))
        
    return said


get_audio()
```

So I've added the `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)` what it does is that, it adjusts the threshold according to the background noises, and then listens to whatever you say.

This should work fine!